# Eclipse 3.7.2 not recognizing ADT after plugin updates

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 with ADT plugin installed.
I updated all the plugins I had by going to the option `Help->Check For Updates`. After the update, on restarting eclipse, I'm no longer able to see any options corresponding to Android/ADT.

I tried re-installing by going to `Help->About Eclipse Platform->Installation Details`
and removing ADT, DDMS, Heirachy Viewer and Traceview.
Then going to `Help->Install New Software..` and installing them again.

But it didn't work. 
I have searched for a solution but none wroked.
Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT:
Giving it 24 hours till I re-install eclipse from scratch.